# How to delete object from realm database in table view controller

Tags: ios, swift, realm

if this is my code then why i get the error: Value of type 'RLMResults' has no member 'arraySortedByProperty' when I'm using realm fore saying data.

```
var items = [NSManagedObject]()

var todos: RLMResults {
    get {
        return ToDoItem.allObjects()
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    title = "Todos"

}


func deleteRowAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    let realm = RLMRealm.defaultRealm() //1
    let objectToDelete = todos[UInt(indexPath.row)] as! ToDoItem //2
    realm.beginWriteTransaction() //3
    realm.deleteObject(objectToDelete) //4
    realm.commitWriteTransaction() //5

     todos = ToDoItem.allObjects().arraySortedByProperty("name", ascending: true) //6

    tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade) //7
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you don't need this line:

```
todos = ToDoItem.allObjects().arraySortedByProperty("name", ascending: true) //6
```

If you want to delete any object from Relam database. Just remove that line and your code will be:

```
func deleteRowAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    let realm = RLMRealm.defaultRealm() //1
    let objectToDelete = todos[UInt(indexPath.row)] as! ToDoItem //2
    realm.beginWriteTransaction() //3
    realm.deleteObject(objectToDelete) //4
    realm.commitWriteTransaction() //5
    tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade) //7
}
```

And you can call this method this way:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {
        deleteRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    }
}
```

Comment: I try above code for delete the row ,But app is crash with "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Invalid array type - container must be an RLMArray, RLMArray, or NSArray of RLMObjects'" erorr

Comment: Error it self explains everything.. :)

Answer (score 0):

The todos property is a get only property so you can't assign it to any value. and also you need to implement your own 'arraySortedByProperty' on whatever type allObjects() is returning or just call sort()

```
var todos: RLMResults {
    get {
        return ToDoItem.allObjects()
    }
    set { todos = newValue }
}

//assuming return value of allObjects has a property called name 
todos = ToDoItem.allObjects().sort { $0.name < $1.name }
```

Comment: Isn't RLMResults an array? what is it if not?

Comment: press alt key and click on RLMResults to find out what it is. I assumed an array because allObjects sounds something to call on a collection

Answer (score 0):

`arraySortedByProperty:ascending:` was renamed with the release of [Realm Objective-C 0.87](https://realm.io/news/realm-cocoa-0.87.0/) to `sortedResultsUsingProperty:ascending:`.

Comment: but my will crash after deleting the cell